# call method from stdclass OOP

Tags: php, static

I have a problem with calling a method from previous instanced static method.

Static method is getting an ID from a user, after that I have to change his password.

I did like this:

```
$user = user::find_user_by_id(2);
$user->password = "asdasd";
$user->update();
```

I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::update()
```

I understand what the problem is, but can't figure it out how to solve that.

This is update method:

```
public function update(){
    $db = db::getConnection()->conn;
    $sql = "UPDATE ".self::$table." SET username=':username', password = ':password' where id =':id'";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username',$this->username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password',$this->password);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password',$this->id);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and find user by id

```
public static function find_user_by_id($user_id){
    $result_set = self::find_query("SELECT * FROM ".self::$table." where id = {$user_id} LIMIT 1");
    $found_user = $result_set->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $found_user;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the entire User class to help answer.

Comment: `$found_user` when returned from `find_user_by_id` should be an instance of your class, not the return value from `fetch()`.

Comment: You are returning an object from a result of an array, not a constructed `User` object. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php

Comment: Very minor point - class names, by convention, should start with an uppercase letter - so probably would be `User`

Comment: @AaronFranco here is the code: https://pastebin.com/6apqY5pk

NigelRen - I know, but how can I do that?
Ice76 - How can return from an object?

Comment: @Ice76 - its working now, no errors, but it won't update in db?
    $found_user = $result_set->fetchObject(__CLASS__);

Comment: What you are doing there is a really bad idea. You are binding your procedural code to a global mutable state.

Comment: Make a constructor for a `user` and upon loading, creating the user object and return it if found.

Comment: I still can't figure this out. Now I can see user Object, and it just won't execute the SQL query. I set If($stmt->execute(){echo "ok";}

and it says OK... but no changes in database..

Comment: I think that `$stmt->bindParam(':password',$this->id);` should be `$stmt->bindParam(':id',$this->id);` in the `update()` method